# why i got "You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, kubernetes

im trying to setup my k8s and connect to aws, but i got this error

```
    jackma@jackma-MacBook-Pro ~ %  kubectl get svc                             
E0202 23:58:23.323851   66169 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0202 23:58:23.822265   66169 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0202 23:58:24.300791   66169 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0202 23:58:24.794799   66169 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0202 23:58:25.279269   66169 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

also, i cannot see detail of my default profile, i got

```
jackma@jackma-MacBook-Pro ~ % aws sts get-caller-identity --profile default                                               

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

i tried reset with `aws configure` after delete my ~/.aws/credentials, but still get this issue. I am able to log in my aws account. here is my aws credential, not sure why i met this issue.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ZSIB2NADXYH5MTSQ29X4
aws_secret_access_key = Wcnlg1GC8zBTuyIMoAheRKDycypSRTGjjcVWTHZv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the front space before equal

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ZSIB2NADXYH5MTSQ29X4
aws_secret_access_key=Wcnlg1GC8zBTuyIMoAheRKDycypSRTGjjcVWTHZv
```

If that not works remove the config files and **re-configure** again

```
aws configure <name-of-the-profile>
```

it will auto-create the files for you again and set necessary things if you manually edited anything have issues.

Comment: i did, but still same issue, i also got this after source it
% source ~/.aws/credentials 
/Users/jackma/.aws/credentials:1: no matches found: [default]

Comment: okay your creds stored in credentials file ?

Comment: it is saved at ~/.aws/credentials
like this now
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ZSIB2NADXYH5MTSQ29X4
aws_secret_access_key=Wcnlg1GC8zBTuyIMoAheRKDycypSRTGjjcVWTHZv

Comment: check profile is set properly in creds and config file

Comment: the creds file is shown as above, and my config file is
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html